# OS X Terminal fn+delete doesn't work, prints ~

Tags: keyboard, terminal

I recently did a fresh install of Mavericks, and ever since I haven't been able to use the <kbd>fn</kbd><kbd>delete</kbd> keystroke in Terminal. On the command prompt, <kbd>fn</kbd><kbd>delete</kbd> prints `~` and if I'm in vim, <kbd>fn</kbd><kbd>delete</kbd> will capitalize existing characters.

How can I reset this in Terminal so it functions normally? (Terminal is the only place I have this problem.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix this by going to Terminal->Preferences->Advanced and choosing xterm-256color as the setting for "Declare Terminal As"

Comment: You should accept this answer, if you're sure this is what solved your problem!